# how to write code for a button on a web page using oracle JDeveloper?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i am new at oracle jdeveloper 12c and tried hard to code a button visual on a web page .jspx but did not find anything. Kindly tell me how  i can code the button's action and get all visuals of the page in that button action's method[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q33JP.png). Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try double clicking the button in the visual editor - it will popup a dialog to help you create an action for the button.
Or just go the the property inspector and click on the right edge of the action or action listener property for the button.